# Strange pattern of non-convergence when flattening in mixed effects logistic regression

Tags: logistic-regression, lme4

I'm running a simulation study on the effects of adding fractional numbers of successes and failures, which I'll call C, to mixed effects logistic regressions. I've simulated 2000 datasets and modeled each with 5 logistic regressions (adding an C of either 1, .5, .25, .1 and .05). The models converge on the  majority of the datasets, but ~200 fail to converge when I add an C of .25 and ~50 fail to converge when I add an C of .5 (Sometimes I get a warning message and sometimes I get implausible standard errors). I very rarely see any evidence of non-convergence with the other values (I've looked at warning messages, standard errors and the ratio of highest to lowest eigenvalues in the random effects matrix). Even in the datasets that fail to converge when C = .25, slightly changing C often solves the problem, such as in this example (data sets available here: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/ro92mtjkpqwlnws/AADSVzcNvl0nnnzCEF5QGM6qa?oref=e&n=19939135)

```
m7 <- glmer(cbind(Data + .25, (10+.5- (Data + .25))) ~ Group*Condition + (1       + Condition |ID),  family="binomial", data=df2)

Warning messages:
1: In eval(expr, envir, enclos) : non-integer counts in a binomial glm!
2: In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
Model is nearly unidentifiable: very large eigenvalue
 - Rescale variables?

summary(m7)
Generalized linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood (Laplace    Approximation) ['glmerMod']
Family: binomial  ( logit )
Formula: cbind(Data + 0.25, (10 + 0.5 - (Data + 0.25))) ~ Group * Condition  +      (1 + Condition | ID)
Data: df2

 AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
7001.1   7040.0  -3493.6   6987.1     1913 

Scaled residuals: 
Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-3.5444 -0.6387  0.0143  0.6945  2.9802 

Random effects:
 Groups Name        Variance Std.Dev. Corr
 ID     (Intercept) 0.26598  0.5157       
    Condition   0.06413  0.2532   0.66
 Number of obs: 1920, groups:  ID, 120

Fixed effects:
             Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)      1.760461   0.001226  1436.5   <2e-16 ***
Group           -1.816952   0.001225 -1483.0   <2e-16 ***
Condition       -0.383383   0.001226  -312.7   <2e-16 ***
Group:Condition -0.567517   0.001225  -463.2   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
             (Intr) Group Condtn
Group       0.000              
Condition   0.000  0.000       
Group:Cndtn 0.000  0.000 0.000 

m8 <- glmer(cbind(Data + .2, (10+.4- (Data + .2))) ~ Group*Condition + (1 +   Condition |ID),  family="binomial", data=df2)
Warning message:
In eval(expr, envir, enclos) : non-integer counts in a binomial glm!

summary(m8)
Generalized linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood (Laplace    Approximation) ['glmerMod']
 Family: binomial  ( logit )
 Formula: cbind(Data + 0.2, (10 + 0.4 - (Data + 0.2))) ~ Group * Condition +       (1 + Condition | ID)
   Data: df2

     AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
  6929.3   6968.2  -3457.6   6915.3     1913 

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-3.5724 -0.6329  0.0158  0.6945  2.9976 

Random effects:
 Groups Name        Variance Std.Dev. Corr
 ID     (Intercept) 0.2698   0.5194       
        Condition   0.0652   0.2553   0.66
Number of obs: 1920, groups:  ID, 120

Fixed effects:
                Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)      1.76065    0.07850  22.429  < 2e-16 ***
Group           -1.81762    0.10734 -16.933  < 2e-16 ***
Condition       -0.38111    0.06377  -5.977 2.28e-09 ***
Group:Condition -0.57033    0.08523  -6.692 2.21e-11 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
            (Intr) Group  Condtn
Group       -0.732              
Condition   -0.033  0.025       
Group:Cndtn  0.029  0.045 -0.758
```

As this is a simulation study, I'm not especially interested in making those models converge, but I'd like to understand why they're not converging. Does anybody have any ideas?

Comment: I would **not** assume that `lme4` is reliable when using fractional values in a model family where integers are expected ... have you double-checked results with `glmmML` or `glmmADMB` ?

Comment: On that data set, the model converged with the parameter estimates I expected when I used glmmADMB. Thanks! Do you know why the two programs differ in this case? I assumed that the binomial Likelihood in lme4 used the log-gamma function rather than the combinatoric function since the majority of models that I added fractional values fit fine. Is this not the case?

Comment: well, there are places where it's not handled correctly: e.g. line 209 of https://github.com/lme4/lme4/blob/master/src/glmFamily.cpp where `dbinom()` is used.  That said, it looks like the binomial deviance residual computation is more general ... see also https://github.com/lme4/lme4/issues/180